# use string translate in url android studio

Tags: android

am try to build weather app use volley  , my code already working fine without any problem . but i want to add language to my app use string , lang English and Arabic . i get weather infromation from wundgeound api . wunground api contant many langauge . am try to get en and ar .

code

```
String url = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/xxxxxxxx/conditions/hourly/forecast10day/geolookup/"+R.string.lang+"/q/"+latitude+","+longitude+".json";
```

when i debug the url

```
http://api.wunderground.com/api/xxxxx/conditions/hourly/forecast10day/geolookup/2131230829/q/33.2379217,44.3381602.json
```

i get the Numbers instead of language ar or en , most be get

```
http://api.wunderground.com/api/xxxxx/conditions/hourly/forecast10day/geolookup/lang:AR or En/q/33.2379217,44.3381602.json
```

String res in en

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="about">About</string>
    <string name="desc">weather</string>
    <string name="forecast">weather forecast</string>
    <string name="satellite">satellite</string>
    <string name="news">news</string>
    <string name="action_settings">setting</string>
    <string name="app_name">weathery</string>
    <string name="navigation_drawer_open">open</string>
    <string name="navigation_drawer_close">close</string>
    <string name="loading">please wait</string>
    <string name="lang">lang:EN</string>

</resources>
```

String res in arabic

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="about">عنا</string>
    <string name="desc">مصدرك الاولى لمعرفة اخر اخبار الطقس و المناخ للعراق</string>
    <string name="forecast">حالة الطقس</string>
    <string name="satellite">الاقمار صناعية</string>
    <string name="news">الاخبار</string>
    <string name="action_settings">ضبط</string>
    <string name="app_name">منظومة ارصاد العراق</string>
    <string name="navigation_drawer_open">فتح</string>
    <string name="navigation_drawer_close">غلق</string>
    <string name="loading">يرجى الانتظار</string>
    <string name="lang">lang:AR</string>

</resources>
```

Comment: `R.string.lang` is integer, and it's only the `id of string`. You have to get that string before using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use

```
String myLang = getResources().getString(R.string.lang);


String url = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/xxxxxxxx/conditions/hourly/forecast10day/geolookup/"+myLang+"/q/"+latitude+","+longitude+".json";
```